# Get minimum value from columns in SQL Server using C# & ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to find the minimum value in "position" column. Here is my code:

```
public void minrank()
{
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(DecryptString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cn"], EncryptionKey2));
    con1.Open();

    string str1 = "select EmailAcmd5hash,eviewdate,MIN(eposition) from rankdata where EmailAcmd5hash=@EmailAcmd5hash and eviewdate=@eviewdate";

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con1);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAcmd5hash", Request.Cookies["li"]["Ac"].ToString());
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eviewdate", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));

    SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader1.HasRows)
    {
        topminranklbl.Text = (reader1["eposition"].ToString());
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Column 'rankdata.EmailAcmd5hash' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All fields must be aggregated or in a GROUP BY. We cannot know what you expect from the result set - simply adding GROUP BY might not be what you want. I suggest you study SQL some more.

Comment: If you only need the minimum position `"select MIN(eposition) from rankdata where EmailAcmd5hash=@EmailAcmd5hash and eviewdate=@eviewdate"` should work.

Comment: What you have posted does not “find the minimum value in "position" column”; it starts to try to find the minimum `eposition` for each `EmailAcmd5hash` and `eviewdate`, for which there may be many, before giving up halfway through. Please explain the result you want because [what you are doing makes no sense at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: #Dan Dumitru Got error "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: eposition" in "topminranklbl.Text = (reader1["eposition"].ToString());" line

Comment: @NarenderGodara that means your query didn't return any rows. If your `eviewdate` field contains a time as well as a date then you will never match the WHERE clause with `DateTime.Now` unless your row happens to be exactly midnight down to the milisecond.

Answer (score 0):

Change query to

```
select MIN(eposition) as eposition
from rankdata
where EmailAcmd5hash=@EmailAcmd5hash and eviewdate=@eviewdate
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add EmailAcmd5hash and eviewdate columns to group by

```
string str1 = "select EmailAcmd5hash,eviewdate,MIN(eposition) eposition from rankdata where EmailAcmd5hash=@EmailAcmd5hash and eviewdate=@eviewdate group by EmailAcmd5hash,eviewdate";
```

or remove from select

```
string str1 = "select MIN(eposition) eposition from rankdata where EmailAcmd5hash=@EmailAcmd5hash and eviewdate=@eviewdate";
```

Answer (score 0):

just refer to the parameter

```
string str1 = "select @EmailAcmd5hash, @eviewdate, MIN(eposition) from rankdata where EmailAcmd5hash = @EmailAcmd5hash and eviewdate = @eviewdate";
```